# Easier way to switch variables?

Tags: java, variables

I have a simple method that goes like this:

```
public int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (a!=b) {
        int q = b;
        b = a%b;
        a = q;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Is there an easier way to write a greatest common denominator? Particularly the three lines in the while loop, can they be simplified?

Comment: There are ways to swap two ints without a temp variable (Google is your friend), are they really "easier"? not sure. Less readable that's for sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code improvement rather than code fixing.

Comment: You could write it recursively, and make it about one line shorter.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int q = b;
    b = a % b;
    a = q;
    return (a != b && a != 0 && b != 0) ? gcd(a, b) : a - b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind performance but just readability then choose a different approach:

```
public int gcd(int a, int b) {
  BigInteger ba = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
  BigInteger bb = BigInteger.valueOf(b);
  return ba.gcd(bb).intValue();
}
```